# local_cosmap remark but can't clear

Tags: ros, local-costmap, 2dcostmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I create 2 laser scan by deepth_image_tolaser, one is middle and one is lower z=2-30cm. 
when I insert or remove object:

- glocal_costmap is clean and mark as obstacle
- local_costmap  is remark obstacle but can't clean

This is my cosmap config.

footprint: [ [0.18, 0.18], [-0.18, 0.18], [-0.18, -0.18], [0.18, -0.18] ]


map_type: voxel


**obstacle_layer:**

  enabled:              true

  max_obstacle_height:  1.2

  origin_z:             0.0

  z_resolution:         0.2

  z_voxels:             2

  unknown_threshold:    15

  mark_threshold:       0

  combination_method:   1

  track_unknown_space:  true    #true needed for disabling global path planning through unknown space

  obstacle_range: 2.5

  raytrace_range: 0.18   #3

  origin_z: 0.0

  z_resolution: 0.2

  z_voxels: 2

  publish_voxel_map: false


  **observation_sources**:  scan scan_low bump

  scan:

    data_type: LaserScan

    topic: scan

    observation_persistence: 0.0

    marking: true

    clearing: true

    min_obstacle_height: 0.1

    max_obstacle_height: 1.2


  scan_low:

    data_type: LaserScan

    topic: scan_low

    observation_persistence: 0.0

    marking: true

    clearing: true

    min_obstacle_height: 0.2

    max_obstacle_height: 0.7


  bump:

    data_type: PointCloud2

    topic: mobile_base/sensors/bumper_pointcloud

    observation_persistence: 6000.0

    marking: true

    clearing: false

    min_obstacle_height: 0.0

    max_obstacle_height: 0.15

  # for debugging only, let's you see the entire voxel grid


**inflation_layer:**

  enabled:              true

  cost_scaling_factor:  5.0  # exponential rate at which the obstacle cost drops off (default: 10)

  inflation_radius:     0.5  # max. distance from an obstacle at which costs are incurred for planning paths.


**static_layer:**

  enabled:              true

  robot_radius: 0.18  # distance a circular robot should be clear of the obstacle (kobuki: 0.18)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258757/local_cosmap-remark-but-can%27t-clear/) by [science00000](https://answers.ros.org/users/25431/science00000/) on ROS Answers with karma: 20 on 2017-04-07

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2017-04-09**:
What is the purpose of "bump" topic? I see that it has `marking: true, clearing: false` in the config

**Comment by [science00000](https://answers.ros.org/users/25431/science00000/) on 2017-04-09**:
Hi, 
I'm using kobuki and astra camera for navigation
fake laser from depthimage_to_laser that is not reliable,
some time hit obstacle below view of astra 
bump topic got data when hit then add to obstacle layer.
sorry the correct is`marking: true, clearing: true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Your raytrace range is super low, 0.18 m, my guess is you're not clearing due to this.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2018-06-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [science00000](https://answers.ros.org/users/25431/science00000/) on 2018-06-20**:
I have solved by add lidar, that sensor is high accuracy and  speed rate.
Fake laser from image have a lot of issue when working in real-office.

[video testing](https://youtu.be/SSb7mn9Khy4)